How do I enforce permissions in a directory with Posix ACL?
I have a directory Mine, and a directory Shared
In Shared, files are created with a default group we, and group permissions default:group:we:rwx
In Mine, files are created with a different group, and no group permissions.
If I create a file in Shared, it is created with the group we, and the specified permissions.
If I create a file in Mine, and then copy it to Shared, ACL enforces/changes the group to we, but not the permissions. The groups permissions will stay as it was when created in Mine: no group access.
How can I have Shared enforce the group permissions when files with existing permissions are copied/moved, so the permissions of Shared is applied to any file copied there.
This is on ZFS with Posix ACL enabled on NixOS.
